# How to compile a C file on OSX targeting a router running BusyBox?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, busybox

I've got access to a router running BusyBox. How can I make a C file that'll run on it? I've tried compiling it on my local machine, uploading to the router and trying to execute, but it obviously didn't work. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need install toolchain for your router hardware and then build your C file using compiler within toolchain. Have a look on http://buildroot.uclibc.org. You obviously dont need whole linux kernel environment but may be it will be easier to get toolchain done.

Comment: How do I build a toolchain for my router hardware? How do I know which "toolchain" it requires? Precisely, what exactly is it that makes a C executable run in some computers and not in others? Is it the linux distro? Is it the processor? Or what exactly is it?

Comment: what is your router model?

Comment: I don't know - all I have is telnet access to it.

Comment: you cannot build a binary out of C without knowing for which platform you build. As well without having specialised experience you can just brick a router. Do you have 'uname -a' available?

Comment: +1 on the answer, and I can only hope the OP adds one more question to their litany: *"Should I be allowed to even **touch** a router until I know how an OS works and what makes them different from other OS?"*, or I sense an expensive life-lesson-maybe-learned forth-coming.

Comment: @WhozCraig what do you mean with that? And how do you suggest I learn it?

Comment: @evilruff there's no 'uname -a' available - I just don't know what you mean with "platform". What is a "platform"? I know the processor, it's an ARM986EJ-S. Linux version 2.6.21.5. BusyBox v1.01.

Comment: @user2302356 It means you should be taking in a **lot** of reading, and using a emulator until you understand what it is you're doing. Its not difficult to write router apps, but it is tedious and potentially dangerous, so you want as much wood behind your arrow as you can get.